# Show abbreviated section name in TOC with Quarto

Tags: html, quarto

Using Quarto markdown, is it possible to show alternative text in TOC, e.g. an abbreviated header text?

What I'd like to have in toc is:

Table of contents

1 First topic

While the first header looks like this:

# Some very long header about the first topic

An HTML solution would be fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using a little bit of javascript, but this solution will only work for `html` output format.

So use the file `abbrv_toc.html` in `include-after-body` and Set the text you want to show in TOC in `toc-text` attribute within the curly bracket just after the section name.

```yaml
---
title: "TOC Abbreviation"
format: html
include-after-body: abbrv_toc.html
number-sections: true
toc: true
---

## Some very long header about the first topic {toc-text="First Topic"}

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code
into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see
<https://quarto.org>.

## Some very long header about the second topic {toc-text="Second Topic"}

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated
that includes both content and the output of embedded code

## More Header

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
```

**abbrv_toc.html**

```html
<script>
  function abbrv_toc() {
    let toc = document.querySelectorAll('nav#TOC li>a');
    toc.forEach(e => {
      let id = e.id.substring(4);
      let sec = document.getElementById(id);
      let toc_text = sec.getAttribute('data-toc-text');
      if(toc_text != null) {
        let new_toc_text = e.querySelector('span').outerHTML + ' ' + toc_text;
        e.innerHTML = new_toc_text;
      }
    })
  };

  window.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    abbrv_toc();
  });
</script>
```

---

[image: Shortened TOC Text]

Comment: I cut and paste your markdown code in a `test_toc.md` file and your HTML code in `abbrv_toc.html`, but it does not seem to work,  I get the long headers in TOC.

Comment: You need to use Quarto document (`.qmd` files), not markdown!

Comment: I noticed that I have to add `toc-text` for every header, even if the TOC entry is not different from the header. Is there a way to use `toc-text` only when there is a difference?  This would make typing easier, especially with Quarto books.

Comment: Another question: How could I add other directives for the header processing, like `{.unnumbered #sec-cross-ref}`?

Comment: @petzi, I have updated the answer in response to your first question. And the answer to your second question, try with `{.unnumbered #sec-cross-ref toc-text="First Topic"}`. Usually, the syntax is `{.class-name #id attribute=attribute-value}`